# Getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS after splitting NSString

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to create a game in which people answer questions. I am having the questions be loaded from a text file. Different parts are separated with • and questions with §. The code for separating works fine, except for when I try to create a question with it.

```
for(int n = 0; n<[questionsFromFile count]; n++)
{
    NSArray *params = [((NSString *)questionsFromFile[n]) componentsSeparatedByString:@"•"];

    NSString *fact = params[0];
    NSString *prompt = params[1];
    NSString *image = params[2];
    NSString *answerAsString = params[3];

    BOOL answer = [answerAsString boolValue];
    YNQuestion *question = [[YNQuestion alloc]initWithFact:fact prompt:prompt image:image answer:answer];
    [self.allQuestions addObject:question];
}
```

In questions.txt:

```
fact•prompt•unknown.png•YES
§fact•prompt•unknown.png•NO
```

When I run it, it works fine until a question is loaded. Then, it crashes with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2)`. If i replace fact, prompt, image etc. to equal @"hello" or @"goodbye" it works fine.

I am using ARC. Also, here is the code for the `YNQuestion`.

```
@interface YNQuestion : NSObject
@property(assign, nonatomic)NSString *fact;
@property(assign, nonatomic)NSString *prompt;
@property(assign, nonatomic)NSString *image;
@property(assign, nonatomic)BOOL answer;
-(id)initWithFact:(NSString *)fact prompt:(NSString *)prompt image:(NSString *)image answer: (BOOL) answer;
-(BOOL)checkIfCorrect: (BOOL)answer;
@end
```

Now, it works. Only with ones that are not my default.

Surprise! It doesn't work again. I believe the error is with having hardcoded answers and answers in the .txt file. I'm testing.

Comment: Please post the header definition for the instance variables / properties in `YNQuestion`. Also are you using ARC, or manual reference counting?

Comment: @JasonHarwig I just did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep strong references to the strings you pass to your initializer. Set NSString properties to strong instead of assign and it will stop crashing.

Comment: Thanks, I think you just made my day.

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing an index that probably doesn't exist in the array. Try logging the `count` of the array, to see how many entries are in the array.

Also, set all-exception breakpoint to see where exactly the app crashes. Or you could set a breakpoint right after you load the array, to see its contents.

Comment: I have done that, and it prints out the correct answer or fact. It just doesn't like being loaded into the question. The strings are correct. Maybe I need to make them constant?

Comment: Then, what are the values of those `NSSTring`s, right before you load the question?

Comment: according to NSLog, they are (in order) ´fact prompt unknown.png NO´

Comment: Try setting the all-exception breakpoint, that could show you what are you doing wrong.

Comment: Btw. what happens if you set the BOOL in the .txt file to 1 instead of YES?

Comment: It seems that it worked once, but maybe because some earlier questions are hardcoded in?

Comment: Now it loads, but when it switches questions it fails.

Comment: Then you must be doing something bad when initializing the question, maybe problems with memory - EXC_BAD_ACCESS often means that you are accessing deallocated object.